# SQLite 3 - Return multiple SELECT with JOIN results to one row

Tags: sqlite

I have 5 **SELECTs** with a **JOIN** in each that individually return the data I'm querying without any issue.  They are:

```
SELECT table1.typeName FROM table1 JOIN table6 ON table1.OwnerID = table6.OwnerID;
SELECT table2.typeName FROM table2 JOIN table6 ON table2.typeID = table6.typeID;
SELECT table3.itemName FROM table3 JOIN table6 ON table3.itemID = table6.moonID;
SELECT table4.name FROM table4 JOIN table6 ON table4.state = table6.state;
SELECT Timestamp FROM table6;
```

What I have been trying to do is take all of these **SELECTs** and return all the data on one row.

The closest thing I tried was a subquery?  that went like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT table1.typeName FROM table1 JOIN table6 ON table1.OwnerID = table6.OwnerID),
(SELECT table2.typeName FROM table2 JOIN table6 ON table2.typeID = table6.typeID),
(SELECT table3.itemName FROM table3 JOIN table6 ON table3.itemID = table6.moonID),
(SELECT table4.name FROM table4 JOIN table6 ON table4.state = table6.state),
(SELECT Timestamp FROM table6);
```

**It worked, but it only returned the first row.**  So I tried doing `UNION ALL` with them.  It worked, but it would return all the data sequentially.

Some columns in table6 have duplicate data and some columns don't.

Is there any way I can return the data on one row?

**EDIT:**  @Makoto.  I'll go a few more steps back.

We have data from a server that dumps data into columns on table6 of the database.  The data in the columns are numeric/alphanumeric code and don't mean anything to the end user.

Now, the other tables have columns with the same numeric/alphanumeric codes AND another column with a description.

So, ***I want to select columns on table6, have it look up the descriptions on the other tables and return the descriptions***, like (based on the information in table6)

`typeName|typeName|itemName|name|Timestamp`

Once the data gets returned like that, I can use Python to create a readable message that is automatically sent to a feed.

Based on my limited knowledge, I thought that something like the SELECT with JOIN commands I put together would achieve this goal, but I can't figure it out.  I suspect I'm going down the wrong path.

Comment: Let's back up two steps.  First, what is the schema of this table?  Second, what is the data you're trying to get at, and why do you believe that it should all appear on the same row?

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: @Makoto and CL, I added some more description.  I'm working on putting something together.  Thanks.